# TP-Link encrypted backup file TX-VG1530

Tags: linux, encryption, embedded

I have been trying to wrap my head round this stuff so bear with me.

I have a Tp-Link TX-VG1530. From the gui you can download the config file however the file is encrypted, I include a portion of the conf.bin file below

```
q=4‡|&YFË#Tùð¶¿Ä/1Þl^àh[Ú‹³lÙ€ÍÁ.©-&ÚdŠDT•°ôy®jò3R7B®5#B5m¨)½=Q›Î\òï-ÏÇëÄ+®‡h•Y‡Í@Ý úò%×ýÛâçó›Ð0&rŸØë÷vj[ñÛx¹Úm‡z†äí}Ös•qêQRsÆðèÍŽ’|Û˜’²³€¬#ìŸ4œä³½nÛÿl„¯~‚,•RÁgÏ;öÏËÀw‡§„,W‰×Jî <§x}ôžZñˆgFPdB§êÁ×gˆÑ=‰»uËžÏHžâKE¢¾.â˜/×3 Åæç±WÔ™ŒiõÁÕƒS\%*
Õ^çý­<w±ø”ð’´<ØmÎF1ˆÀqû§‘¥ðÛAÈÎ-ÿ1z”­9]ã7”…b«Yå[ö„*i'{ü'NŒÀç‘4ÑáÐm¹ü´B·U^wª½IÙ‚8û]³#)Lû-Diž
```

Using firmware modification kit I am able to  extract the file system and looking at the upload page for the conf file (/web/main/backNRestore.htm) I can see the following

```
formObj.target = "up_frame";
formObj.action = "/cgi/confup";
formObj.submit();
```

Doing a quick grep I can see that /cgi/confup appears in /usr/bin/httpd. looking at this with IDA pro

[image]

From the following post I believe I should be able to retrieve the encryption method but I cannot seem to see anything relating to keys etc

[http://teknoraver.net Decrypting TP-Link conf file](http://teknoraver.net/software/hacks/tplink/)

I include a link to the file here

[httpd file link](https://ufile.io/2pu39)

Using the strings command on the file I see nothing that relates to `aes`, `des`, `md5`, `key`, `dec`, `enc` etc.

There are some tools such as [tlrecode.sh](https://gist.github.com/NikitaKarnauhov/5d9129f13e7b0e257cfbe93215751c7a) which appear to decode the file slightly (this script seems to utilise the same key found in the teknoraver post), the decrypted file is not 100% though

```
×<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DslCpeConfig>
  <InternetGatewayDevice
  <Summa¯ry val=".:1.1[](Baseli`ne:1, EthVLA`N:1)"
```

Can anyone suggest the next steps to take

Comment: /cgi/confup seems to be registered to the function at 0x015744 which appears to parse the POST data for the file and then calls rdp_updateFirmware (imported function) and then reboots. I would look for the library where rdp_updateFirmware is defined.

Comment: @cimarron many thanks for the tip. I will dig a bit deeper using this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems they also added compression there.
This utility seems to decode it: 
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/router_password_recovery.html
Also, I'd just written my own decoder and encoder for it:
https://encode.su/threads/3005-TP-LINK-router-config-compression

Decrypting:
**openssl enc -d -des-ecb -K 478DA50BF9E3D2CF -nopad -in conf.bin -out conf.lztp**


Unpacking:

```
struct lztp_t {
  byte  hash[16];
  uint  size;
};

uint bitbuf, bitnum;

uint getbit( void ) {
  uint r;
  if( bitnum==0 ) {
    bitbuf = byte(get());
    bitbuf|= 256*byte(get());
    bitnum =16;
  }
  r = (bitbuf>>15)&1; bitbuf<<=1; bitnum--;
  return r;
}

uint getvar( void ) {
  uint r = 1; do r = 2*r + getbit(); while( getbit() );
  return r;
}

int decode( void ) {
  uint c,i, winptr, id, l,d;

  enum{ winlog=16, winsize=1<<winlog, winmask=winsize-1 };
  byte win[winsize];

  lztp_t hdr;
  for( i=0; i<sizeof(hdr); i++ ) if( (c=get())==-1 ) break; else ((byte*)&hdr)[i]=c;
  if( c==-1 ) return -1;

  winptr=0; bitbuf=0; bitnum=1;
  while( winptr<hdr.size ) {
    id = getbit();
    if( id==0 ) {
      // literal
      c = byte(get());
      put( win[(winptr++)&winmask]=c );
    } else {
      // match
      l = getvar()-2+4;
      d = (getvar()-2)*256;
      d+= byte(get()) + 1;
      while( l-- ) {
        c = win[(winptr-d)&winmask];
        put( win[(winptr++)&winmask]=c );
      }
    } // if id
  } // while

  return 0;
}
```

Compression algorithm is similar to LZSS - has interleaved streams of
bits and bytes, rather than a single bit stream like eg. deflate.
But unlike LZSS, also uses bit stream/bitcode for length and distance
values.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Could you please include relevant algorithm for decryption, if possible (for your own tool!). Basically, if that linked hoster goes down or the forum closes down, your answer will be worthless. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, didn't think of it.

Comment: @Shelwien great work, I have checked the tool myself and it works a treat. If you notice it has the serial in the config file which explains why when I upload the file to another device it changes the serial number of that device. I played around with tr69 with this unit but as the serial changes to the one in the config file I ended up with 10 devices all reporting under the same serial rendering it useless, good old TP-Link.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted code Shelwien for linux/gcc

```
#define uint int
#define byte char
#define put(c) putchar(c)
#define get() getchar()
#include <stdio.h>


struct lztp_t {
  byte  hash[16];
  uint  size;
};

uint bitbuf, bitnum;

uint getbit( void ) {
  uint r;
  if( bitnum==0 ) {
    bitbuf = get();
    bitbuf|= 256*get();
    bitnum =16;
  }
  r = (bitbuf>>15)&1; bitbuf<<=1; bitnum--;
  return r;
}

uint getvar( void ) {
  uint r = 1; do r = 2*r + getbit(); while( getbit() );
  return r;
}

int main( void ) {
  uint c,i, winptr, id, l,d;

  enum{ winlog=16, winsize=1<<winlog, winmask=winsize-1 };
  byte win[winsize];

  struct lztp_t hdr;
  for( i=0; i<sizeof(hdr); i++ ) if( (c=get())==-1 ) break; else ((byte*)&hdr)[i]=c;
  if( c==-1 ) return -1;

  winptr=0; bitbuf=0; bitnum=1;
  while( winptr<hdr.size ) {
    id = getbit();
    if( id==0 ) {
      // literal
      c = get();
      put( win[(winptr++)&winmask]=c );
    } else {
      // match
      l = getvar()-2+4;
      d = (getvar()-2)*256;
      d+= get() + 1;
      while( l-- ) {
        c = win[(winptr-d)&winmask];
        put( win[(winptr++)&winmask]=c );
      }
    } // if id
  } // while

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use this. I would also like to reencrypt after.